# Netty Dependency Issue Running Spark 2.4.3 on Amazon EMR

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run a simple Spark SQL application on Amazon EMR. Version of Spark is 2.4.3 and EMR 5.26.0. I receive a NoClassDefFound error from the Netty library immediately upon trying to create the SparkSession.

I've tried explicitly overriding the Netty dependencies to the versions used by the Spark dependencies with no luck. I can build and run the jar locally with no issue.

build.sbt:

```
resolvers += DefaultMavenRepository

name := "test-spark-sql"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.4.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion exclude ("org.apache", "zookeeper") exclude ("org.apache.spark", "spark-core")
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided"
dependencyOverrides += "io.netty" %% "netty-all" % "4.1.17-Final"
dependencyOverrides += "io.netty" %% "netty" % "3.9.9-Final"

// test suite settings
fork in Test := true
javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx2048M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled")
// Show runtime of tests
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-oD")

// JAR file settings

run in Compile := Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Compile, mainClass in (Compile, run), runner in (Compile, run)).evaluated
runMain in Compile := Defaults.runMainTask(fullClasspath in Compile, runner in(Compile, run)).evaluated

assemblyJarName in assembly := "test-spark-sql.jar"

test in assembly := {}

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org","aopalliance", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "inject", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "google", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "codahale", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "yammer", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
  case "META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mailcap" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mimetypes.default" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "git.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

Main.scala:

```
package com.test.spark.sql

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val spark: SparkSession = {
      SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("spark session")
        .master("local")
        .getOrCreate()
    }
    import spark.implicits._
    val someDF = Seq(
      (8, "bat"),
      (64, "mouse"),
      (-27, "horse")
    ).toDF("number", "word")
    someDF
      .show()
  }
}
```

Stack trace of error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.defaultNumHeapArena()I
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyUtils.createPooledByteBufAllocator(NettyUtils.java:113)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.<init>(TransportClientFactory.java:106)
    at org.apache.spark.network.TransportContext.createClientFactory(TransportContext.java:99)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.<init>(NettyRpcEnv.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnvFactory.create(NettyRpcEnv.scala:462)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:424)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at com.test.spark.sql.Main$.main(Main.scala:11)
    at com.test.spark.sql.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

Comment: on EMR, the master might be `yarn` not local.